# ANTLR TestRig ClassCastException

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Very basic question. I've been trying to follow some examples for ANTLR4 to generate a lexer and parser grammar for the XML language. Both XMLLexer.g4 and XMLParser.g4 are in the same directory.

I'm getting this error when trying to run TestRig

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class XMLParser
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3640)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:135)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)
```

(I didn't get any error when executing org.antlr.v4.Tool or javac)

What's strange is that if I combine the lexer and the parser grammars in a single file, I can successfully run TestRig.

Any hints to what's going on will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Jay

Comment: What does your command look like? For Windows, I ran `java -cp "c:/Users/Kenne/.m2/antlr4-4.10.1-complete.jar;." org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig  XML document -gui ../examples/books.xml` after generating a Java parser and building.

Comment: I'm on Linux, I saved my command in a .sh file.  `java -cp ".:/./antlr_4_10_1/antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig $*` and I execute it with `antlr_grun.sh XMLParser document -gui test.xml`

Comment: It should not be "XMLParser", but "XML"!! Do not append "Parser" to the grammar name. Also, your full path to the jar is weird: "/./......". Copy the path and do an "ls -l /./antlr_4_10_1/antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar" and verify that it exists.

Comment: hmmm, where does "XML" come from? in my .g4 file my grammar name is `parser grammar XMLParser;`

Comment: This is a split grammar, not just a parser grammar. Read the code, https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/14703f21b5802e880da8c3afe80824ab651aee07/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/gui/TestRig.java#L123, and look at variable "grammarName". It must be "XML".

Comment: oh wow, not very intuitive but I get it now. Thanks!